# Keep state of Infragistics UltraGrid column swapping (position changed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

I am using Infragistics UltraGridView to display data on a Web form. 
Infragistics allows me to swap columns and change the position easily.

The problem I am having is that when there is postback or when my page is auto refreshed, the UltraGrid changes back to its initial position with no column sorting.

I want to keep the column position/state as it is, even if there is postback or auto refresh.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Search for LoadPreset and SavePreset methods of the UltraWebGrid http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/46633.aspx